# Pass vector of card into function to print and use?

Tags: c++, vector, poker

I'm struggling through a card program and want to pass my single card vector into my function so it can be used. Right now, I'd just like to test to see if it can print the cards from the deck, but passing it into a player hand is the ultimate goal. What's the best way to pass this vector for use in functions?

Thanks in advance!!

function to create deck:

```
void Deck::createDeck() {
deck.clear();
static const char suits[] = {'C','D','H','S'};
for (int suit=0; suit < 4; suit++)
    for (int val=1; val <=13; val++)
        deck.push_back(Card(val,suits[suit]));
}
```

function to pass the card to:

```
void Card::printCard(Card& drawnCard) const { //for debugging purposes
cout << value << " of " << suit << endl;

}
```

prototypes have been declared in header as follows:

```
class Card{
public:
    int value;
    char suit;
    string drawnCard;
    Card(int value, char suit) : value(value), suit(suit) {}
    void printCard(Card& drawnCard) const;
};

class Deck {

public:
    void createDeck();
    void shuffleDeck(Card);
    Card drawRandomCard();
    Deck(); 
    vector<Card> deck;
};
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to critique here. You probably don't want to pass the list of cards directly, but probably want to pass the deck, instead, like:

```
 void DoSomething(const Deck& deck) {
    // ...
 }
```

However, assuming you do pass the list, the way to pass it would be as a const reference:

```
void DoSomething(const std::vector<Card>& cards) {
   // ...
}
```

There are many other areas, though, where your sample code could be improved. For example, the data fields of Card and Deck should probably be "private" and only accessed through accessor functions as appropriate. In addition `printCard` does not need to take a Card as input, since it operates on `this` (and, if it did take a parameter, a function that simply prints an object should take its parameter by a const, not a mutable  reference).

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelsafyan/0a62e42aa50be661430b) for an example.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate all the advice. So using your first example, would the prototype be placed under Deck class and be `void printCard(const Deck& deck)` then my function is `void Deck::printCard(const Deck& deck)` but I don't think the values from the card vector are now being passed because my value and suit are `not declared in this scope`? Thanks!

Comment: No, it would be "void Card::printCard() const" or "void PrintCard(const Card& card)". If you have "Card::" as the prefix and it isn't static, though, you are already in the context of a specific card and to do not the card as a parameter.

Comment: This is the prototype? I'm just confused as to where it would go under since I have a deck class and a card class. Thanks again.

Comment: I think you might find this illustrative: https://gist.github.com/michaelsafyan/0a62e42aa50be661430b

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That does help a lot. This is basically the first time I've had to connect a bunch of stuff together so I'm running into lots of problems, but thanks for posting this.